# Use function from a structure in class

Tags: ios, swift, function, class, structure

I am new to Swift and I have trouble using classes and structures.

I have a Structure called Workspace:

```
struct Workspace: Decodable {
var guid: String
var name: String

func getUserWorkspace(base: String, completed: @escaping () -> ()){
        //some code
    }
}
```

Here is my class User:

```
public class User {

    var Wor = [Workspace]()
    var WorData:Workspace? = nil

   //+some other var & functions
}
```

So what I'm doing in my view controller is this:

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var listView: UITableView!

var co = User()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    co.WorData?.getUserWorkspace(base: co.Base) {
        print("success")
        self.listView.reloadData()
        self.updateVertically()
    }
    listView.delegate = self
    listView.dataSource = self
}
```

The problem is that the code never goes inside the function co.WorData?.getUserWorkspace(base: co.Base)

Before I put it in the structure it was directly in the class but since I changed it it doesn't work anymore so I think I might be calling it the wrong way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WorData` is nil.

Conditional unwrapping (`co.WorData?.getUserWorkspace(base: co.Base)` will check WorData has a value before trying to call the method. If it was nil and Swift didn't do this, it would crash.

You either need to set it as new all the time

```
var worData = Workspace()
```

Set it after class init

```
var user = User()
user.worData = Workspace() // or pass a specific one in
```

or require your User object to be initialised with a Workspace

```
class User: NSObject {
    var wor = [Workspace]()
    var workspace: Workspace // use lower camel case for var names

    required init(workspace: Workspace) {
        self.workspace = workspace
    }

}
```

Comment: Please, please **never ever** declare properties in a class as implicit unwrapped optional which are initialized as non-optional in an `init` method. You might be surprised but you won't get a compiler error when you remove the exclamation mark. 

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll remove that